# What are all the possible downsides of not closing a datareader in .Net framework?

Tags: .net

I am looking for a comprehensive analysis on the side effects of not closing it. Example: Effect on connection pooling, memory, etc.,

Answer (score 1):

Among other problems you won't be able to open another datareader with the same connection